# How can I use a regular expression to remove the file extension in zhell?

Tags: java, regex, zsh

I am trying to simplify my command line java using this zshell script where `$1` holds the file name, in this case `Hello.java.`

```
# jcr stands for java compile and run
jcr() {
  javac $1    # $1 contains the first argument Hello.java
  java Hello  # I want to replace Hello with a 
              # regular expression or similar which extracts Hello 
}
```

I need a good reference or cheat sheet for zshell and zhell regular expressions.

Comment: For your case, using a regexp is overkill, but it is of course a good idea to know about them. You start reading about regular expressions in zsh at _man zshmisc_ , in the chapter _CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS_. From this you will see that zsh can do two types of regexp: Extended POSIX (default), and PCRE (must be turned on if you want to use it). About PCRE, you find information in _man zshmodules_

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple string substitution: `${1//.java}` This will remove the last occurence of `.java` from the parameter `$1`.

Comment: Thanks, can you break down the syntax though with a brief explanation for what each part does?

Comment: Even simpler, `$1:r`. `r` is one of the modifiers that you can apply to history expansions and parameter expansions.

Comment: @chepner : Good point and very elegant! It should be noted however that this will remove **any** possible extension, not only `.java`. The OP did not say what behaviour she wants to see in this case. The proposal in this answer is at least slightly safer, in that it removes **only** _.java_.

Comment: The `javac` command is going to fail if `$1` doesn't end in `.java` anyway. I'd probably use `javac $1 && java $1:r`.

Comment: `${1//.java}` will remove all occurrences of `.java` in the string - try it with `a.javax.java`. Use `${1%.java}` to remove just the `.java` extension.

Comment: @jenniferk. - the [Parameter Expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) documentation has descriptions of these operators.